# Launch Instance with smaller root volume storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to launch an instance with custom size of root volume on Amazon EC2.

At step no.4 - Add Storage, the root volume default setting came with a default snapshot and a default 10 size (GiB). Then I lowered the size into 5GiB.

> But at the final step, it wouldn't allow me to launch the instance because of only 5GB root volume.

Any idea or solution that I can lower the size when launching an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an Amazon EBS volume that is smaller than the snapshot that you want loaded.

You could attempt to make your own AMI by launching with 10GB, attaching a 5GB volume, copying files across, turning it into an AMI, etc but frankly it isn't worth the bother.

If you are merely wishing to save money, then at 10¢ per GB per month, it would only save 50¢ per month.